# Querying distinct columns across rows filtering by another column

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm working on a project using Linq and Entity Framework Core.

I'm struggling with a query.

I have two data access models.

```
public class JobPost
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string RoleTitle  { get; set;}
  public Domain Domain1 {get;set;}
  public Domain Domian2 {get;set;}
  public Domain Domain3 {get;set;}
  public Domain Domain4 {get;set;}
  public Domain Domain5 {get;set;}
}

[Owned]
public  class Domain
{
   public int? CategoryId {get;set;}
   public int? SubcategoryId {get;set;}
}
```

A job post is an entity/table with Id as key. It has one role title(mandatory) and 1-5 domains(this explains why Id properties of Domain is nullable). Domain has CategoryId and SubcategoryId as keys. Job seekers will be able to filter job posts by domains.  Examples on domains are:

```
            Category      Subcategory
Domain      IT            Mobile
Domain      IT            Database
Domain      IT            Design
Domain      Transport     Driving
Domain      Transport     Spedition
```

Two domains are distinct if they differ by their categoryId OR subcategoryId.

**User case for the query in question:**
User(Employer X) has posted 3 job posts:  Y ,Z and  W. Both Y and Z have "Sotware developer" as role title while W has"Front-end developer". Job post Y has one domain: IT,Mobile. Job post Z has two domains: IT,Mobile and IT,Database. Job post W has one domain: IT,Design. 
User now wants to create a third post. User clicks on the +Post button and is prompted to either select a previous role title("Sotware developer" or "Front-end developer") or create a new one. In this case, user selects "Sotware developer" from the previous-item list. Next, user is prompted to submit domains. We want to make it easy for our user by presenting a selectable list of distinct domains that has been previously applied for job posts with role title "Software developer". In this specific case there are two domains on the list, "IT,Mobile" and "IT,Database", which the user can apply.

So the question is how do we write this query in Linq so we get an IEnumerable of all distinct domains that are applied for a specific role title across all job posts, performed by SQL server and NOT by the client.

I've tried different strategies such as projectiong, joining, grouping in Linq but without the results I want. The only way I can  do this is to retrieve all job posts filtered by role title and remove duplicates in my viewmodel.

```
from p in dbCotext.JobPosts
where p.RoleTitle == roleTitle
select p

//client code for removing duplicates, not what I want
```

Is it even possible to do this in Linq or do I have to write this query in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct domains"?  Can you describe the result you are looking for and what you have tried?

Comment: Why doesn't JobPost have a collection of Domains, instead of 5 different Domain properties.  Seems like it would make your query easier.

Comment: that would put my domains in a seperate table and i dont want that...

Comment: Why don't you want that?  It's the proper relational design, and your current design is obviously causing problems.

Comment: bcause i dont see domains as entities, and also because of performance.

Comment: What is the definition of "distinct domains" to you?  Same `CategoryId` and `SubCategoryId` or something?

Comment: Distinct is when 2 domains differs in categoryId or subcategoryid, for example  domain x IT(category),Mobile(subcategory) is distinct from domain y IT, Database

Comment: If you don't see domains as entities then use [a collection of owned types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types).

Comment: @GertArnold thanks, I'am beginner in linq and it has been a frustrating day. could you give further thoughts on how a query  might look like for retrieving a collection of unique domains(different categoryId AND subcategoryId) by role title based on a collections of owned types.

Comment: But I don't understand your model and I strongly doubt its efficacy. What's the use of two domains having the same values? And why 5 domains? And why are both ID values nullable? What _is_ a domain here anyway? And do the category IDs themselves refer to anything?

Comment: @GertArnold Domain consists of  categoryId and subcategoryId ex IT,Mobile and acts as filtering.  5 domains/per post? it's a business rule.  Ids are nullable because domain 2-5 (min 1 domain/post) are optional allowing the columns in database to be null. One job post cannot have domains with same ids . But several  job posts with role title X will have intersecting domains.  So next time employer wants to post a job with role title X they will get a unique list of suggestions on previous domains they applied with that role title. Hope things got more clear...

Comment: @GertArnold I have updated the content of my previous post by adding a user case. /Thanks

Comment: The problem remains that you have a model that violates the lowest required *Normal Form* for working smoothly with any ORM (3NF). The first violation is that the domains don't depend on the key and nothing but the key: the second domain can only be filled when the first domain is, etc. The second one is that  `CategoryId` and `SubCategoryId` are redundant. Subcategory "Mobile" implies category "IT", etc. I think that in reality, you have a many-to-many association between `JobPost` and a `SubCategory` entity that is restrained to at most 5 items.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you Gert! I've posted an answer. An inner join.

Answer (score 1):

```
 PreviousSubcategories =
          from c in dbContext.Categories
             let posts = 
             from p in a.Posts p in dbContext.Posts
             where p.RoleTitle == roleTitle
             where (c.Id == p.Domain1.CategoryId
             || c.Id == p.Domain2.CategoryId
             || c.Id == p.Domain3.CategoryId
             || c.Id == p.Domain4.CategoryId
             || c.Id == p.Domain5.CategoryId
             orderby p.CreatedOn descending 
             select new Domain[]
                   {
                     p.Domain1,
                     p.Domain2,
                     p.Domain3,
                     p.Domain4,
                     p.Domain5
                   }
            where posts.Any()
            select new DomainViewModelDto
                  {
                      SubcategoryId = (int)c.Id,
                      SubcategoryName = c.Name,
                      LatestExperienceLevelsApplied = new LatestExperienceLevelsApplied
                      {
                          IsExperienceLevel1Applied = (bool)posts.First().Where(d => d.CategoryId == c.Id).First().IsExperienceLevel1Applied,
                          IsExperienceLevel2Applied = (bool)posts.First().Where(d => d.CategoryId == c.Id).First().IsExperienceLevel2Applied,
                          IsExperienceLevel3Applied = (bool)posts.First().Where(d => d.CategoryId == c.Id).First().IsExperienceLevel3Applied,
                          IsExperienceLevel4Applied = (bool)posts.First().Where(d => d.CategoryId == c.Id).First().IsExperienceLevel4Applied,
                          IsExperienceLevel5Applied = (bool)posts.First().Where(d => d.CategoryId == c.Id).First().IsExperienceLevel5Applied,
                          IsExperienceLevel6Applied = (bool)posts.First().Where(d => d.CategoryId == c.Id).First().IsExperienceLevel6Applied,
                      }


                  }
```